# Is Escala's «Clubbed to Death» a passacaglia?

Tags: electronic-music, musical-forms, modern-music

Escala's [*Clubbed to Death*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pM5g4i7VjDE) seems to be a passacaglia. It has a repetitive line throughout, over which counterpoint is added. In fact, it sounds similar to Biber's [*Harmonia artificiosa-ariosa: Partita No. 5 in G Minor: V. Passacaglia*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2HoDJMr_NU).

Comment: Maybe you should reword as "is C2D best categorized as a passacaglia or some other form"  to get more thoughtful responses.

Comment: You might want to give Rob Dougan a bit of credit for C2D, though as others have mentioned he did have some help from Elgar. The "original" 1995 version is [on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RomEFY8CEP4)

Comment: @Bob Dougan's piece is very good. Re-use doesn't mean uncreative. Bach reused Vivaldi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, nice find!

"Clubbed to Death" actually begins with the opening to Elgar's [Enigma Variations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GbD20h8-_4), at which point Escala takes a part of that opening bassline and uses it to construct the form.

The definitions for "passacaglia" and "chaconne" are really a little bit vague, but there are some typical aspects of each. The passacaglia, for instance, is often in 3 (like the Biber example you showed).

But both the passacaglia and chaconne are examples of what we call a "[ground bass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostinato#Ground_bass)," so I think it would be safer to just call it that.

Comment: Yes, it begins with Elgar's _Enigma Variations_, but the "ground bass" line is very similar to Biber's passacaglia.